Dynamic LCA: Modification of Multiple Exchanges in One or More Activities
I am working on building an hourly consumption mix LCA model for an electricity grid. To achieve this, I used Activity-Browser to update and model each technology (e.g., solar PV, wind, etc.). The contribution of each technology to the consumption mix is represented as an exchange.
My plan is to use Brightway 2.5 to dynamically modify the exchange amounts for each technology based on hourly data. For example, here is a representation of the hourly consumption mix:
  Hour   Biomass  Natural Gas     Hydro    Solar       Wind   Imports
0     0  0.044560     0.296973  0.193629  0.118828  0.256997  0.089014
1     1  0.043051     0.205872  0.205036  0.136175  0.237763  0.172102
2     2  0.046465     0.126948  0.210244  0.151587  0.243857  0.220899
3     3  0.045191     0.118660  0.214444  0.151929  0.230907  0.238869

Currently, I am iterating over each hour to update the exchange['amount'] for each technology and saving the changes with exchange.save(). During the same iteration, I perform the LCIA calculation. However, this process involves thousands of iterations, and even a few iterations take too long.
My question: Is there a more efficient way to dynamically modify multiple exchanges in one or more activities?
Thank you in advance!

Yes, there is - you can feed a suitably configured array of the possibilities directly to the matrix constructors and skip the relational database entirely. See notebook two from https://try.brightway.dev/ (mirrored at Github), and in particular the section Using arrays for scenarios.
You will need to spend a bit of time figuring out how to construct the arrays. To get the static datapackages you can use prepare_lca_inputs.
